# ssh connection timed out when using no-ip hostname to connect to raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, lan

I am having trouble connecting to my raspberri from a different newtwork. I have already forwarded port 22 to my raspberry ip, I have given my raspberry a static ip in the router.I have also created and succesfully logged in into no-ip on my router. I have linked my public ip adress to my no-ip hostname. When I try connecting to my raspberry pi I get the error connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

You normally will have to set up port forwarding in the router to do that.

In addition, to reach the router from the outside, you would need a static ip or some sort of dynamic DNS or such.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your pi or router firewall is dropping your traffic. If no, check your router configuration to add the pi to DMZ (demilitarization zone) list